# Thread got suspended after the put operation in SynchronousQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This is my code

```
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;

public class Mywork {

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    SynchronousQueue<String> s=new SynchronousQueue<>();
    Producer1 p1 =new Producer1(s);
    Producer2 p2=new Producer2(s);
    new Thread(p1).start();
    new Thread(p2).start();
 }
}

class Producer1 implements Runnable
{
 SynchronousQueue<String> s=null;
 Producer1(SynchronousQueue<String> q)
 {
    this.s=q;
 }

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    try {
        s.put("Suman");
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
 }
}
//
class Producer2 implements Runnable
{
 SynchronousQueue<String> s=null;
 Producer2(SynchronousQueue<String> q)
 {
    this.s=q;
 }
 @Override
 public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        s.put("Ghosh");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
 }
}
```

whenever the put is performed after that I am not ale to debug it , the control vanishes from the eclipse

any idea why it is happening ?
[image: Screenshot reference]

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html#put(E)):

The `put` method will block until another thread retrieved data from `SynchronousQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

[`put(E o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html#put(E))

> Adds the specified element to this queue, ***waiting if necessary for
>   another thread to receive it.***

That said, `SynchronousQueue` will not return until there is a corresponding take() call. And, you are adding element in both thread and caused `wait`.

So, changing

```
s.put("Ghosh");
```

to

```
String str = s.take();
```

will continue execution.